# Flask.g database connection - RuntimeError: Working outside of application context

Tags: python, flask

I am attempting to assign the database connection to `Flask`.`g` so that it is accessible throughout my entire application.

However I am getting error:

```
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
```

---

File `app/database/__init__.py`

```
from flask import current_app, g
from .connection import Connection


class Database:
    def __init__(self, app):
        if 'db' not in g:
            g.db = Connection(app)

    def get(self):
        if 'db' in g:
            return g.db
        else:
            g.db = Connection(current_app)
            return g.db
```

File `app/database/connection.py`

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras
from ..error import DatabaseConnectionFailed


class Connection:
    connection = None
    cursor = None

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.connect(app)

    def connect(self, app):
        try:
            self.connection = psycopg2.connect(
                user=app.config['APP_DB_PSQL_USER'],
                password=app.config['APP_DB_PSQL_PASSWORD'],
                host=app.config['APP_DB_PSQL_HOST'],
                port=app.config['APP_DB_PSQL_PORT'],
                database=app.config['APP_DB_PSQL_DATABASE'],
                application_name=self.client(app)
            )
            self.connection.autocommit = True
            self.cursor = self.connection.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
        except (psycopg2.NotSupportedError, psycopg2.ProgrammingError, psycopg2.DataError, psycopg2.IntegrityError, psycopg2.InternalError, psycopg2.OperationalError, psycopg2.DatabaseError, Exception) as e:
            raise DatabaseConnectionFailed()
        else:
            logging.warning('Connected successfully to database!')
```

`app/__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, redirect  
from .database import Database  


def create_app(settings):
    app = Flask(__name__)     
    app.config.from_object(settings)
    
    Database(app)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create the `Database()` object in your application factory, you are adding the connection to `g.db` as you noted. However `g` is bound to the current application context. This is a problem because...

> The application context is created and destroyed as necessary. When a
> Flask application begins handling a request, it pushes an application
> context and a request context. When the request ends it pops the
> request context then the application context. Typically, an
> application context will have the same lifetime as a request.
>
> https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/appcontext/#lifetime-of-the-context

Instead of storing your connection in `g` you should store it in a python variable that is importable from other parts of your app.

Create your `Database()` object in a file called `database.py` and store it in a variable for example. Add then import it into your application factory and call `connect` in the factory.

Then anywhere you need the database, import it from `database.py`.

Also have a look at the `Flask-SQLAlchemy` project as it is a much nicer way of doing what you are trying to do.

Comment: When uWSGI creates a worker i want to initiate the connection to the database and keep it open for the lifetime of the worker. How can i achieve this? Do I need to create the connection outside of `create_app()`? I don’t want to use SQLAlchemy.